# Erro no pyautogui, valores

Tags: python, python-2.7

Eu quero criar um macro que execute algumas tarefas.

[OK] 1° Passo: Recordar o **X** e **Y**.
COD:

```
def recordMouse():
time.sleep(5)
print "New record in 3s"
x, y = pyautogui.position()    
c = open('Position.txt', 'a')
c.write(str(x) + ":" + str(y) + "\n")
c.close()
print "X ["+str(x)+"]  Y ["+str(y)+"] Position added!"
pyautogui.click(x,y)
mouse()
```

[OK] 2° Passo: Ler linha por linha e enviar para click
COD:

```
def readLine():
arq = open("Position.txt", 'r')
texto = arq.readlines()
for linha in texto :
    sendMouse(str(linha))
    #print linha
arq.close()
```

3 passo: Dar o click

```
def sendMouse(line):
if ":" in line:
    dados = line.split(":")
    x = dados[0]
    y = dados[1]
    print "Click on: X:"+str(x)+" Y:"+str(y)+""
    pyautogui.click(x,y)
else:
    print("Line error")
```

Nesta parte, devo separar o **X** e **Y**, pelo **:**(dois pontos).
Até ai tudo bem, o erro vem na hora de dar o CLICK.

pyautogui.click(x,y)

ERROR:ValueError: The supplied sequence must have exactly 2 elements (3 were received).

Informa que estou enviando 3 valores, sendo que estou enviando apenas 2(X,Y)
O : não está sendo enviado, ele serve apenas para separar.

Comment: O propósito do módulo [`PyAutoGui`](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) é *somente* simular operações com o mouse e com o teclado e *não fornece* interface para a captura de *clicks* do mouse. Se o intento da função `recordMouse()` é capturar os clicks do mouse, isso não é possível com a `PyAutoGui`.

Comment: Use o módulo [`Pynput`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynput) para gravar o mouse e o teclado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode corrigir o problema reescrevendo a função sendMouse, de forma que ao enviar os valores, faça isso usando uma lista e valores convertidos em inteiros. Ou seja, da seguinte forma:

```
def sendMouse(line):
  if ":" in line:
        dados = line.split(":")
        x = dados[0]
        y = dados[1]
        print("Click on: X:"+str(x)+" Y:"+str(y)+"")
        pyautogui.click([int(x),int(y)])
  else:
        print("Line error")
```

Comment: Observação: Reescrevi seu código aqui, e agora ele parece rodar corretamente.